# Why are my input fields dissapearing when I change them to buttons?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

this is the part that will check:

```
if (exercise.syllables.length === correctSylls.length) {
    $(this).closest('.syll-row').find('input.syl-input').replaceWith(getCorrectBtn());
    S.addRight();
    S.playRight();
}
```

and when correct it should change into this:

```
function getCorrectBtn() {
    var correctBtn = $('<button/>', {
        'class': 'btn btn-success buttonCorrect',
        'type': 'button',
        'id': "button" + CBC++
    });
}
```

Instead of changing to a green bootstrap button it just dissapears.

Css:

```
.btn {
    margin: 0;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 38px;
    margin: 5px;
    outline: none !important;
}

input {
    width:100%;
    padding:5px;
    outline: none !important;
    text-align: center;
}

input[type="text"] {
    font-size: 150%;
    margin-top: 1vh;
    transition: color 1s;
}
```

Comment: `getCorrectBtn` does not return the `button`

Comment: Found it out myself just a second ago haha. You beat me to it. Put it as an answer and I will upvote and check it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`getCorrectBtn` function does not return the created button. Add a `return` statement.

```
function getCorrectBtn() {
   var correctBtn = $('<button/>', {
       'class': 'btn btn-success buttonCorrect',
       'type': 'button',
       'id': "button" + CBC++
   });
   return correctBtn;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Return is missing here in**  `function getCorrectBtn()`

```
function getCorrectBtn() {
    var correctBtn = $('<button/>', {
        'class': 'btn btn-success buttonCorrect',
        'type': 'button',
        'id': "button" + CBC++
    });
    return correctBtn;
    }
```